# Powershell and group policy

Tags: windows, power, powershell-2.0

Please help!
I have created a "vbs" to call a powershell command to move computer account to a certain "OU".
This failed because it can't call **AD powershell module**. So if i run the powershell in the **AD module** that works for me.
If i run  the **powershell traditional module** that failed.

what i am trying to do is to use group policy to move computer accounts to an "OU"

Answer (score 0):

You can get an list with

get-module -listAvailable

Now you can pick the AD Module (don't know the name) and add it within the powershell command or scriptlet like

SNIP - code.ps1

import-module $MODULENAME
$YOUR_CODE_HERE$

SNIP

Now you call the vbs script exec "powershell code.ps1" and all should be fine.